# How to set a password for workspaces?

Tags: workspaces

Is it possible to set a password for workspaces?Such that if i switch from one workspace to another it should prompt for password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with current window managers.
Your best bet (if you use compiz) would be to write a compiz plugin, but I can't think of any other straight forward solutions.