# Set password for specific workspace

Tags: unity, gnome, password, workspaces

I would like to set a password for a specific workspace W so that when I (or someone else using my user session) tries to switch to that workspace, they can't do so unless they know the user password.
This comes in handy especially when I want to leave my work untouched and yet lend the machine for a few minutes to someone for something.
There exists a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36450/how-to-set-a-password-for-workspaces) for a similar issue but it does not have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You *can* set some kind of a password protection to use an arbitrary viewport, but it would be quite easy to move windows from the targeted viewport to other viewports, *and* it would be unavoidable to see a glimp (flash) of the viewport when trying to enter it. Not the full-proof solution you are prabably looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add an authentication step to "switch to workspace". So, you cannot do what you asked.

However, you could lock your screen, and let your guest use a Guest session - no password, only civilian access, vanishes at logout.